# Why is the output of processes is abnormal and the program is not successfully terminating?

Tags: c

The output of printf in the parent process is printed before the hostname and the children output are printed after it and the program is not successfully terminating what is the reason?

the code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/wait.h>
#include <unistd.h>

void main() {

  if (!fork()) {
    printf("p1\n");
  } else if (!fork()) {
    printf("p2\n");
  }

  else
    printf("parent");
}
```

output:

```
abbas@abbas-VirtualBox:~/Desktop$ ./fork 
parentabbas@abbas-VirtualBox:~/Desktop$ p2
p1
^C
abbas@abbas-VirtualBox:~/Desktop$ ^C //I have to click ctrl c for it to exit
abbas@abbas-VirtualBox:~/Desktop$
```

Answer (score 2):

On my machine this exits neatly, though the prints are in indeterminate order.

```
~/Desktop $ ./fork
p1
parentp2
~/Desktop $
```

I think you're just seeing the forks writing to unexpected places in your terminal, since there's no synchronization.

Just hitting `ENTER` would probably also get you a new shell prompt.

Comment: The enter button does that but I am looking for a way for it to get to a new shell prompt automatically I think return or exit will do it.

Comment: That's not the issue here. You are getting a shell prompt once the parent program dies, it's just that the children continue on and print over and around the shell prompt. Heck, you can even try writing `ls` when you would otherwise hit ctrl+c.